# For which values of $k$ can all planar graphs of girth $k$ be coloured with less than or equal to 3 colours?

Tags: graph-theory, coloring, planar-graphs

Let $G_k$ be the family of planar graphs that do not contain cycles of length less than $k$. Determine for which values of $k$ the following statement holds:

For all $G \in G_k$, $\chi(G) \leq 3$.

Any help appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Any $k \geq 4$ works, by [Grotzsch's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6tzsch%27s_theorem) (which states that a triangle-free planar graph is 3-colourable).
This is apparently difficult to prove. Showing that $k\geq 6$ is easier, and is proven in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/242714/all-connected-planar-graph-with-girth-at-least-6-are-3-colourable).